# How to filter values after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and I'd like to groupby a field and then select only values which is not zero as my aggregate function and then convert them into a list. Here is the code I have

```
df.sort_values(by='col1').groupby('col2').apply(lambda x: x if x!=0).apply(list)
```

However if says `invalid syntax`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the first function to `apply` into a `lambda` and do the filtering there:

```
(df.sort_values(by='col1')
   .groupby('col2')
   .apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y != 0]))
```

Comment: It's also possible to use `lambda x: list(filter(None, x))`.